# Is it possible to draw a single line chart with different colors portion of that line chart in dc.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

Is it possible to draw a single line chart just like in image with different colors portion of line chart in dc.js. Can it be done with color accessor or there is another way for both ordinal charts or linear charts.

[image: Required Situation]

Comment: As long as I know, it's impossible to specify more than one 'stroke' attribute for a <path> element. Just create a few <path> elements, each with a different 'stroke' value.

Comment: There is nothing built-in to dc.js to do this. As @MichaelRovinsky says, since dc.js uses a single path element for each line, there is no way to color individual segments different colors. I speculate that you might be able to force separate paths by putting each color as a different stack, with all other stacks [undefined](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/LineChart.html#defined) where they are not active. But that seems like a pain, really forcing dc.js to do something it's not designed to do.